# Neither user 10036 nor current process has android.permission.DEVICE_POWER.

Tags: android, android-permissions

I need to power off device by button on my application.
I add permission to manifest file:

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"/>
```

And use powerOff method on click button:

```
void powerOff(){
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(this.POWER_SERVICE);
        pm.goToSleep(SystemClock.uptimeMillis());
    }
```

When I click button I get error:

> Neither user 10036 nor current process has
>   android.permission.DEVICE_POWER.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DEVICE_POWER` is a restricted permission. PackageManager won't grant you this unless your app is signed with the system signature.

Comment: Sorry to say, but you can't -- unless you created your own firmware and "own" the device.

Comment: Hi, Can you explain more ? how to signed with the system signature ?

Comment: You can only sign with the system key if you create your own image. It's far from trivial.