# How to grant my application android.permission.DEVICE_POWER

Tags: android, android-permissions

I need power off from, my application: [Neither user 10036 nor current process has android.permission.DEVICE_POWER.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726352/neither-user-10036-nor-current-process-has-android-permission-device-power/15726409?noredirect=1#15726409)
But I get error, because my app is signed with the system signature. How is fix it?

Comment: Did you try to push your app to `/system` partition?

Answer (score 0):

Standard apps can't get this permission as it's level 2 permission.

Comment: I think the OP is implying that his app is signed with the platform key, i.e. not a standard app.