# android.permission.DEVICE_POWER error

Tags: android

When I did some job on android widget of setting, I got this error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10097 nor current process has android.permission.DEVICE_POWER.

I have pushed the widget apk to the system/app.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.fly.widget.setting02"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIMAX_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIMAX_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_KEYBOARD_LAYOUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USERS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONFIGURE_WIFI_DISPLAY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name=".SetProvider" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/appwidget_provider" 
            android:enabled="@bool/has_powercontrol_widget"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
           <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="com.android.sync.SYNC_CONN_STATUS_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Your application must be accessing power management. Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#DEVICE_POWER). Add the permission in manifest, and you should be fine.

Comment: I  have added the permission like this  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"/>
the function GPS works well , but the power gets error

Comment: Under application tag? Can you please edit question with manifest?

Comment: Not the application tag . There's nothing wrong with my code .

Comment: Ok. But it would be better if you show manifest file, so someone can help you.

Comment: hey,i added the manifest

Comment: possible duplicate of [Neither user 10036 nor current process has android.permission.DEVICE\_POWER.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726352/neither-user-10036-nor-current-process-has-android-permission-device-power)

Comment: I dont know how to sign the app with the system signature

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DEVICE_POWER permission is not accessable by third-party applications like yours.

```
public static final String DEVICE_POWER
Added in API level 1

Allows low-level access to power management.

Not for use by third-party applications.
Constant Value: "android.permission.DEVICE_POWER"
```